# Accessing an excel Project from A Winform Project in same Solution

Tags: c#, excel, solution

I am trying to open an excel project in my Solution from a Winform Application. Please note:

1. Winform is my starting Project.
2. I **can** add Winform Reference in Excel but I **can not add Excel Reference in Winform Project**.

[image: Screenshot of both projects in same solution]

As I mentioned I **cant find** Excel Project in **ADD REFERENCE>SOLUTION of Winform project**. I also cant add it manually (Invalid dll or COM file Error!).
Any idea?

Comment: Just to clarify - what you are looking for is a working library to work with Excel through code, using managed objects? By the way, awesome color theme.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: I'd like to open excel project by clicking a button in win-form application. Simply

Comment: As if you double-clicked it's icon on your desktop?

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Like Application.Run(**EXCEL WORKSHEET**)

Comment: I doubt we would expect the same thing when using `EXCEL WORKSHEET` in the context of `Application.Run`... Do you want Excel to really open up with the project?

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Yup! thats exactly what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open up excel you can use this:

```
Process.Start("excel.exe"); // or the real path of excel
```

And to have it open up with a certain worksheet, you could pass as an argument the path of the file:

```
Process.Start("excel.exe \"c:\My Folder\book1.xlsx\"");
```

Comment: my excel file is in another project and I'd like to call it from the project not static path. Here is another link of what u suggesting but it isnt what I need. take a look at this:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257580/how-to-show-open-start-excelworkbook-projectsheet1-from-windowsform-project)

Comment: You can use the `Application.ExecutablePath` to get the path of the exe that is the start-up of your project, and from there build a "static" path.

Answer (score 0):

i think iam not really getting what you mean but if you need to open the excel file with one click in the app 
and you dont want to write the path of the excel file (may be because you want you app portable)
so the answer is to 1- put the excel file anywhere in the project folder 
2- add existing item (*.* filter) and select the excel file
3-change the properties of the excel file 
build action: resource 
Copy to output directory:copy always
4-open the properties of the solution and click resources the drag the file and drop it
5-use the (using system.reflection & using system.io & using system.resources)
then write the code like this

```
string sPath = Path.GetTempFileName();


    File.WriteAllBytes(sPath, Properties.Resources.excel File name here);
```

then take that (spath) and use it as your path so then you can change the project location with the excel file inside it and it will still be working without writing a constant path for it